# Long polling with react query

Tags: reactjs, long-polling, react-query

Would like to ask for suggestions on implementing long Polling with useQuery. i.e. send a new request only when response comes back, and request will wait on the server until new events or some changes happens and maybe some time out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.